# WebRTC: ICE failed error in browser with Mesibo Video/Audio chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, webrtc, mesibo

I am working on a video/audio chat application in React and Django using Mesibo Javascript SDK.

It is working locally on the same network but when trying to connect through different networks, Firefox browser gives me this error

> WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more
> details.

In Chrome, this error doesn't show up but still the video/audio chat is not working and gives me

> Mesibo_OnCallStatus: 50.

I noticed that Mesibo uses `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` as the STUN server and tried changing it to `stun:stun.l.google.com:19305` but of no use. I even created a `numb.viagenie.ca` account to add a TURN server which worked for a few minutes and then gave this error

> webrtc: ice failed, your turn server appears to be broken.

When checked on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/, chrome is giving **error code:701** for all the above turn/stun servers whereas firefox doesn't.

As suggested by Mesibo Documentation, my website is fully secure with https and the Rest APIs are called from Django backend. I'm invoking https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js as a script tag in the index.html file in react. I'm also able to successfully get

> Mesibo_OnConnectionStatus=1

and the incoming call notification is also working. Upon answering the call, the call status changes from 3 to 5 and gives this webrtc error after sometime without any video/audio rendered.

Please suggest any hint/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Enable webrtc for remote calling you need your own trun server.

**Google don't provide free trun server.**

**Free Turn Servers are will not work well in production. Well Fell Free to try Your Luck on Them. Not All Are borken**

You Need to create Your Own on Cloud like DigitalOcean,AWS.
Or For Tetsing purpose I have a Trick

**Soloution.**

1. If Your Doing the testing

   Probably you can try to use some Google TURN servers that they use here
   https://test.webrtc.org/, I just checked for browser console and found this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n62CF.png)

**Not Sure About LifeTime. But you will get that.**

2. For Production I will suggest to used DigitalOcean 5$ plan which is very chip.

   And you install **your own TURN server using [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)  on it**

If you want You can also use
**[Node-turn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-turn)
which is great for node backend.**

There is also heroku option of setup

I don't know is there any django or python option.

(tip: try your to build turn server on hosting server. Make sure the port on which server is running is open)

Comment: I checked the turn servers provided in test.webrtc in trickle-ice, and found they don't work without credentials. Also, since Mesibo is a priced communication API, shouldn't it be providing us the TURN server also?

Comment: Thanks, I added the turn and stun servers as mentioned in test.webrtc.org and it started working.

Comment: Well I am not familler with mesibo api so I thought it would be like numb . So they must have something in there sdk check there doc properly. If I found Something I Will let you know

Comment: I have just checked there docs . Maybe you follow there doc from [here](https://mesibo.com/documentation/conferencing/#fundamentals-of-group-messaging--group-calling) if you alreay have there api key